# Plotly Dash - Callback triggers sometimes & the same callback doesnt trigger sometime

Tags: callback, plotly-dash

I am facing issue with callbacks.  I have 3 drop downs, one scattermap , one table and one slider on the screen and they all need to work in tandem and i have 5 call backs. When i execute the application all my callbacks associated with these controls execute in random order. After that when i click on scattermap it may or may not work. Say we assume it worked. Then i can navigate all around without any hassle. Then if i execute the application then click on the scattermap then as i mentioned it may or may not work. Say suppose it didn't work this time. If so is the case it will not work at all no matter what i do and simulaneously one specific dropdown also becomes dysfunctional. However if click any of the other two drop downs then evrything will start functioning as normal.

I have digged really deep into this and figured out that this has nothing to do with my code. The underlying issue is that when the click doesn't work the reason the reason behind that is the callback isn't getting triggered. I found out this by applying some debugging techniques and i am 100% sure the callback is not firing. Can anyone help me resolve/understand this please.